# Error in writing an algorithm

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics, simulation

I have been trying to write an algorithm in order to generate some observations, yet I am confronted with a mistake I do not know how to fix. You can find my code below and if you need to check what my algorithm is supposed to do, please consult this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80934/accept-reject-for-beta-distribution).

```
n = 10
u1 = runif(n)
u2 = runif(n)
alpha = 2
beta = 2
v1 = u1^(1/alpha)
v2 = u2^(1/beta)
w = v1+v2
x = rep(0,n)
for(i in 1:n){ if(w[i] <= 1){x[i] = v1/w}}

Warning messages:
1: In x[i] = v1/w :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Can you please tell me how to fix that without altering the nature of my algorithm? Thank you in advance.

PS Happy new year!

Comment: Possibly `for(i in 1:n){ if(w[i]<=1) { x[i] = v1[i] / w[i] } }`? And fwiw I would initialize `x` to `NA`s

Comment: @achingfingers This is R-code as you could have seen from the tags.

Comment: Agree with Jake on the indexing. You could avoid loop: x[w<=1] <- (v1/w)[w<=1]

Comment: @JakeBurkhead No such error now but something's not right yet. It's probably on the statistical side of things though.

Comment: @JakeBurkhead Figured it out! It was my fault for writing x<-rep(0,n). All these zeroes corrupt the statistical properties of the proposed distribution. Thanks man.

Comment: If you have a solution to your problem, please post it as an answer.

Comment: We only have the code you give above, and the problem that leads to the error you state is that you forgot two `[i]` (see my answer), not with initializing to 0. However, please feel free to add an answer if you do not agree.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra The suggestion I received here helped fix 90% of the problem. The other part was the fact that because of the command $> x<-rep(0,n), I had too many zeroes in my resulting simulation. I deleted it and all was right afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you assign a vector to `x[i]`, leading to the error you see. What you probably meant is:

```
for(i in 1:n){ if(w[i] <= 1){x[i] = v1[i]/w[i]}}
```

which can better be replaced by:

```
x = ifelse(w <= 1, v1 / w, x)
```

Some general remarks:

- `for` loops are generally not needed, use vectorization. In this case that is using `ifelse`.
- Use longer variable names, this makes your code much easier to read.
- Use more spaces, this also makes the code easier to read.
- Use indentation if appropriate, e.g. for the `for` loop:

  ```
  for(i in 1:n) {
      if(w[i] <= 1) x[i] = v1[i] / w[i]
  }
  ```

  this also improves readability.

Comment: Since I have not encountered the command ifelse before, would you mind telling what the arguments in the parentheses stand for? It seems like a convenient shortcut and I would like to use it again.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `ifelse`? Use `?ifelse` to access it. If this doesn't make things clear, please feel free to ask a new question.